# Invalid Hijrah Day of Month : 31

Tags: java, android, hijri

I tried to create a simple activity with a button and a textview that showing the date. The button should show the HijriDatePicker dialog when clicked. I tried to make it using ummalqura-calendar and by the dialog, i tried use the HijriDatePicker to create the dialog.

However, after many attempts, it doesn't work. Sometimes the activity will stop when I click the button, and sometimes it just crash. I tried already for many fail attempts.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 13658
    com.github.msarhan.ummalqura.calendar.DateTimeException: Invalid Hijrah day of month: 31
        at com.github.msarhan.ummalqura.calendar.HijrahChronology.getEpochDay(HijrahChronology.java:255)
        at com.github.msarhan.ummalqura.calendar.HijrahChronology.toGregorian(HijrahChronology.java:697)
        at com.github.msarhan.ummalqura.calendar.UmmalquraCalendar.set(UmmalquraCalendar.java:259)
        at net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker.date.hijri.HijriDatePickerDialog.getEndDate(HijriDatePickerDialog.java:1028)
        at net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker.date.hijri.MonthAdapter.getCount(MonthAdapter.java:146)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:493)
        at net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker.date.hijri.DayPickerView.refreshAdapter(DayPickerView.java:142)
        at net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker.date.hijri.DayPickerView.setController(DayPickerView.java:114)
        at net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker.date.hijri.DayPickerView.<init>(DayPickerView.java:105)
        at net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker.date.hijri.SimpleDayPickerView.<init>(SimpleDayPickerView.java:32)
        at net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker.date.hijri.HijriDatePickerDialog.onCreateView(HijriDatePickerDialog.java:340)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

and my main activity java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HijriDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    TextView tvDate;
    TextView etDate;
    HijriDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener setListener;

    public MainActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvDate = findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        etDate = findViewById(R.id.et_date);


        tvDate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            UmmalquraCalendar now = new UmmalquraCalendar();
            HijriDatePickerDialog dpd = HijriDatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );
            dpd.setMinDate(new UmmalquraCalendar(1440,0,1));
            dpd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        assert getFragmentManager() != null;
        HijriDatePickerDialog dpd = (HijriDatePickerDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Datepickerdialog");
        if (dpd != null) dpd.setOnDateSetListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(HijriDatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: " + dayOfMonth + "/" + (++monthOfYear) + "/" + year;
        System.out.println(date);
        etDate.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, it feels like this could actually be a bug in either one of the components (the calendar or the date picker). Could you verify if `now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` actually returns 31? Because I don't think it should ever do that in this code, but the exception message does suggest that.

Comment: Im so sorry i didnt mean to roll back, maybe some problems on my phone keep lagging as i open it on car. Thank you for editting. Really appreciate it

Comment: @JoachimSauer I couldnt, may you tell me how to verify it ?

Comment: Either add a breakpoint and inspect it with a debugger or [log it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log).

Comment: Sorry! You were using (`hijricalendar`) Hijri in question but, why you are using Hijrah in title?

Comment: im sorry as someone update the question, it showing differently. i update the correct one. thank you.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the debugger just show the error. I tried to log it, but no result showed

Comment: @JoachimSauer the system print out 5, so is this a bug ?

Comment: Just to inform, i checked the source code of HijriDatePickerDialog.java setting the date of month to 31. Compared to the real source code on github, it shows 29. So now im stuck to changing the read-only file.

Comment: The umalqura calendar never has 31 days in any month. It is either 29 or 30 days.

Comment: @MenoHochschild yes it is. However when i check the HijriDatePickerDialog.java class, it showed 31. May i know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be a known bug in the msarhan-library. There was also a meanwhile closed [issue](https://github.com/msarhan/ummalqura-calendar/issues/26) on its related website. It indicates that a fix has been applied in the newest version.

So I suggest you to **update your marhan library to version v2.0.2** which might solve your problem.

### Update:

When looking at the date-picker-library you use we can see that it still uses the [version v2.0.1](https://github.com/alhazmy13/HijriDatePicker/blob/10fd1ce99543e90e9dd403af402b2f09ca2de35f/library/build.gradle#L47). Either you wait until the author of the date-picker-library fixes the dependency or you build your own version of the date-picker-library.

Comment: i use the 2.0.2 ver.

Comment: I cannot update it to 2.0.2 version as i get duplicate class error

Comment: The duplicate class error originates because you try to use directly the fixed dependency while your date picker libary still uses the buggy library => version conflict. I am not a build expert but there must be a way in the build configuration to tell the date picker library not to use the buggy version anyway. Good luck.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I changed the lib version to 2.0.2 and I still have this problem and it occurres when I chose day 30 then in another month choose day 29

Answer (score 0):

If you use koltin this method will fix your issue

```
 fun selectDateOfBirthHijri(context: Context, editText: EditText, childFragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
       val now = Calendar.getInstance()
       val dateOfBirthClickListener =
           HijriDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
               now.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
               now.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
               now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
               editText.setText(
                   Formatter.format(
                       now.time.toString(),
                       Formatter.EEE_MMM_DD_HH_MM_SS_ZZZ_YYYY,
                       Formatter.DD_MM_YYYY
                   )
               )
           }
       val ummAlquraCalendar = UmmalquraCalendar()
       val b = HijriDatePickerDialog.newInstance(
           dateOfBirthClickListener,
           ummAlquraCalendar.get(UmmalquraCalendar.YEAR),
           ummAlquraCalendar.get(UmmalquraCalendar.MONTH),
           ummAlquraCalendar.get(UmmalquraCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
       )
       b.maxDate = UmmalquraCalendar(ummAlquraCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
           ummAlquraCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
           ummAlquraCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
       b.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.hint_date_of_birth))
       b.show(childFragmentManager, "HijriDatePickerDialog")
   }
```